# customer name is not visible in newsletter conformation mail

Tags: email-templates, html, phtml, undefined-variable, global-variable

We want to contact our registered customers in the newsletter confirmation mail with their names. Every template we tried to configure the names weren't shown in the mails. Anybody out there who's able to tell why the first- and lastnames in the newsletter mails aren't shown?

our [magento-1.8.1](/questions/tagged/magento-1.8.1)

*We tried using the following variables from the documentation that doesn't work:*

```
{{htmlescape var=$customer.name}}

{{var customer.name}}

{{var customer.firstname}} {{var customer.lastname}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dennis,Magento do not `save customer firstname and last name` in `newsletter` model so ,you `can  not` get customer name in email template

You need customization for this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155784/adding-a-custom-field-to-magentos-subscription-module/6425683#6425683

http://www.justonestepsolutions.net/2012/08/add-firstlast-name-in-newsletter-module.html

Comment: amitbera, can you put relevant codes along with this answer and notify questioner to accept this answer. As you already no, link only answers is not good. However you deserve +1 for the very fist point that you have shared through your answer

Comment: rakesh ..  i  am on magestackday.work on answer section.i will reply later.....

Comment: me too bro. this is a part of filtering. By the buy this time you forgot my real name. It's Rajeev :-)

Comment: Sorry ... Rajeev..:)

Answer (score 0):

For display register customer first name add the {{var customer.firstname}} variable in your email template as you want display. It is working for me only for register customers not for guest user.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to get name of customer in Newsletter

> {{trans "Hello %customer_name," customer_name=$customer.name}}

Comment: Not working in 2.4